# Reading web.config settings file system performance

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-config, settings

Does reading web.config settings via
`WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Setting1")` or `WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Conn1").ConnectionString` cause physical access to underlying web.config file each time it happens?

If yes, will wrapping those setting in shared (static) methods

```
Public Class MyAppSettings
    Public Shared Function Conn1() As String
        Return WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Conn1").ConnectionString
    End Function
    Public Shared Function Setting1() As String
        Return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Setting1")
    End Function
End Class
```

change the way how web.config is accessed? Will settings be cached until web.config file is modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every call to those methods will cause physical access to web.config.  Wrapping them in static methods changes nothing, physical access occurs on every call.

Comment: Has frequent access to web.config significant performance influence compared to putting those settings inside .dll file (however we loose ability to change settings at run-time)?

Comment: Physical access always takes longer than hardcoding the values, but we're talking about a millisecond or two, it's not significant and the value gained by having the ability to make changes to the "system" at runtime far outweighs the performance "hit" in my opinion.

Comment: I have done some further research and found out, that web.config is cached in memory once accessed for the first time. So it does not cause physical access to the file. Source: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/785097/Web-Config-is-Cached